# how to find index of value without looping in python

Tags: python, numpy, loops, matlab

i have some variables :

- ***intensity*** that shape is (***Lenght*** : 480, ***Width*** : 640)
- ***L***, the value is 256
- ***result***, all the value is 0, and the shape is like ***intensity*** (***Lenght*** : 480, ***Width*** : 640)

here is my code

```
for index in range(L):
    for l in range(Length):
        for w in range(Width):
            # print("no")
            if np.round(intensity[l][w]*255+1) == index:
                result[l][w] = (intensity[l][w]/intensity_max)**gamma[index]
                print("(",l,"-",w,")","result: ", result[l][w], "index : ", index, "intensity: ", intensity[l][w]*255+1)
```

i want to find the value in ***intensity*** which when *'np.round(intensity[l][w]*255+1)'** is equals to ***index***
then i use the ***intensity*** value that i get with some calculation for ***result***

actually it can run but i have to wait for a long time. maybe there is way that can make it faster? thankyou

[Edited]

for 1 ***index*** it can be find more than 1 value of ***intensity***, so i want to get the ***last intensity that found***
the example is like the image below :
[image]

so when index 4, the intensity is found in [256,500] [111,563] [127,528] until [282,479]. then i want to use the value from the last intensity found which is [282,479]

actually i try to use code that i found in matlab so i change it to python
[image]
maybe i misunderstand with this example code?

and here is the formula from the code

[image]

maybe there is another way to solve it? thankyou

Comment: Beware *numpy is not Python*. Numpy containers have special methods, and very special processing. For example the equality between 2 arrays is an array when the equality between 2 python objects is expected to be a boolean... But you are right on one point: numpy containers and python loops should never be mixed.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like it would make more sense to loop over `Length` and `Width`, and then compute the index for that specific pixel (assuming that these are pixels of an image?), this why you are only looping once over the image, rather than 256 times

Comment: @FlorentMonin yes that are pixels of an image, actually i'm a little confused too why the example code in matlab loop it 256 times. i attach the formula for the code, maybe there is another way to do that?

Comment: Ignore the matlab code and follow the formula, it's clear that you only need to iterate over _u_ and _v_ like Florent says. Just set `index = np.round(intensity[l][w]*255+1)` before you compute the result value.

Comment: There's probably a way to do it as a one-liner with numpy, but the python loop will speed you up plenty.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, please? Do you have a link/reference to the source of the formula where its function and terms are defined? Thank you.

Comment: why do you use indexing like `intensit[i][j]` but the Matlab uses `intensity(i,j)`?  That suggests to me that  you haven't spent much time reading numpy basics.

Comment: Do `np.round(intensity*255+1)` and `(intensity/intensity_max)` once outside the loops should help with speed.  Move as much of the work outside the loops.  Even in MATLAB that should improve speed (even though MATLAB 'jit's the loops.  I suspect you could write something like `result[mask] = value[mask]`, where the mask and value arrays are derived from the above calculations.  But without a [mcve], I'm not going to try write an testable answer.